# Getting error while creating order?

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am using the PHP library with osc. while creating an order I used the credentials to check through the scratchpad https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html with following request parameters.

### Request Details

```
POST
mws.amazonservices.com
/FulfillmentOutboundShipment/2010-10-01
AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxx&Action=CreateFulfillmentOrder&DestinationAddress.City=Bayonne&   DestinationAddress.CountryCode=US&DestinationAddress.Line1=Test%20suite%20101& DestinationAddress.Name=Test&DestinationAddress.PhoneNumber=1234567890&DestinationAddress.PostalCode=07002&DestinationAddress.StateOrProvinceCode=New%20Jersey&DisplayableOrderComment=test&DisplayableOrderDateTime=2014-10-26T18%3A30%3A00Z&DisplayableOrderId=1&Items.member.1.DisplayableComment=xxxxxx&Items.member.1.PerUnitDeclaredValue.CurrencyCode=USD&Items.member.1.PerUnitDeclaredValue.Value=1&Items.member.1.Quantity=1&Items.member.1.SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId=1&Items.member.1.SellerSKU=xxxxxx&SellerFulfillmentOrderId=1&SellerId=xxxxxxx&ShippingSpeedCategory=Standard&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2014-10-27T06%3A16%3A25Z&Version=2010-10-01
```

### Response

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentOutboundShipment/2010-10-01/">
   <Error>
     <Type>Sender</Type>
       <Code>InvalidRequestException</Code>
       <Message>Seller is not registered for Basic fulfillment.</Message>
   </Error>
    <RequestId>7ab9f920-6644-4f90-a568-62f7aa4e2a87</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Can anybody please let me know where I am doing it wrong? I have put the tax information correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We are successfully using the PHP library to integrate WordPress (WooCommerce) and FBA

That error response probably means:

1. You have not registered for FBA with your Amazon Seller account and/or
2. You have not registered with MWS ( which you can do here: https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/registration/register.html ) and/or
3. There is a typo in your AWSAccessKeyId or SellerId or you forgot to include your awsSecretAccessKey in the request.

If your SellerId in the request was truly correct, then you might not have the FBA service active on your Seller Account.